# Can't convert URL to String

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to find whether a URL contains "https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/". When converting the URL to a string the code gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. I have also used `toString()` and haven't found any successes with that either. When logging `value.href` to the console it prints `undefined`, and when logging `value.toString()` it prints `[object Object]`. When logging just `value` it prints the full URL. Thanks

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(request.message === 'storage update') {
        chrome.storage.local.get("data", value => {
            if(value.href.indexOf("https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/") > -1) {
                chrome.downloads.download({
                    url: value
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**network.js**

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  function (request) {
      chrome.storage.local.set({"data": request.request.url});
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'storage update'})
  }
)
```

Comment: I would assume that using `chrome.storage.local.get` would return the value as a string. What is `value`?

Comment: And `value.indexOf` did not work either?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ```value``` is the requests' request [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0zpi.png).

Comment: @CBroe just ```value.indexOf``` returns ```TypeError: value.indexOf is not a function at <URL>```

Comment: chrome.storage.local.set is an asyncronous api. You have to send your message in  chrome.storage.local.set callback function.

Comment: Alternatively you could not save "data" in storage.local in network.js and send "data" in the message embedded in an object. Then upon receiving the message in background.js, you can save "data" in storage.local.